# Correct equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, data-analysis

What is the correct equation which describes the following dates:

270, 180, 135, 112.25, 101.25.

I've obtained data whit the equations:

- 180    + 90    = 270
- 135    + 45    = 180
- 112.5  + 22.5  = 135
- 101.25 + 11.25 = 112.25
- 95.625 + 5.625 = 101.25

I need this equation to put insert inside a **for** cycle in a matlab script.
I'm looking for something like:

180+(90*(j+1)*.../...)

where **j** varies: j = 1:5

Can you help me?

Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (I don't know Matlab syntax): $$90+180*2^{(1-j)}$$